# Tracing vector map from GeoTIFF for Garmin

Tags: geotiff-tiff, vector, garmin, trace

My goal is to create a vector map for my Garmin GPS by tracing over a topo raster.  The vector data would be exported in ESRI SHP format and later converted for Garmin.  So far, I can load the geotiff layer, however am stumped on creating a vector layer.

Where do all the shapes come from to trace on the map?

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of possibilities, depending on the data you want to see on the Garmin, and the device model you have.

Some Garmin devices allow to store custom made raster maps wrapped by a kmz file. The size of those maps is limited by Garmin.

Almost perfect would be to use the mkgmap toolchain used by Openstreetmap. The points, lines and polygons can be styled the same way as for openstreetmap, but is not limited to their licensing model. You can create overlays which can be put on top of a OSM map, or as a seperate map (which is once again depending on the options your device offers). To use mkgmap, you have to save your data in OSM format.

The cgpsmapper software works similar, but without using OSM data structures.

If you only need some lines and points, you could as well export your geometry to GPX format.

The remaining problem for you is how to get tiff raster data to vector format. QGIS has a vectorize function, but for me, manually digitizing works faster, with better results.

Answer (score 0):

IMapMan http://www.mapman.org.uk/ was made specifically for this.
It doesnt handle georeferenced tifs. Instead it has its own internal georeferenceing procedure for scanned images such as jpg.

If you however re project your raster into WGS84 lat/lon then pick out some previously known lat/lon points on the image you get a good result.

Basic functionality is free but it also includes some paid edge finding functionality which can be usefull.